# Terraform Single source for storing fetching variables

Tags: git, automation, terraform

need some ideas around the below workflow in Terraform.

I am trying to structure a work flow where I would:

1) Store data files (Variables) in one centralize location.

2) Store TF Plan/module files in another location (These would then consume the above data files for substituting data to the variables and finally apply to infrastructure)

Essentially keeping the TF Plans separate and varaible data separate.

Any suggestions on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Please edit your question to be more explicit where you need help and what you've already tried.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me does it make more clear now?....I am a bit new to Terraform...more of an Ansible user...Have a use case that i am trying to research from Terraform perspective.

Comment: that is better, have you tried anything yet that you've had specific problems for? Have you read through the Terraform docs have more specific questions in mind? Why is it that you want to keep variables and TF code separate?

Comment: Hi @Yep_It's_Me I am open to suggestion. I have been successful in keeping the Vars separately by using local-backend and storing them in module. However I am string struggling how I could I possible have modules just fetching variable data from one single file and keep applying the state to the infrastructure and add it to tfstate instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I structure terraform like this:

- `variables.tf`

  - this stores variable definitions
  - eg. "I require a database hostname and password as strings
  - this is committed into version control
  - this DOES NOT store the actual database hostname, password or other sensitive variables
  - this allows terraform to verify that you pass in the variables during run time
- `terraform.tfvars`

  - stores sensitive variables
  - eg. `database_password=shhhdonttell` (hopefully more secure than this)
  - this IS NOT committed to version control because it stores sensitive data
- `terraform.tfvars.dist`

  - a skeleton of `terraform.tfvars`
  - developers will copy paste this to `terraform.tfvars` and fill in the blanks
  - eg. `database_password=<add database password here>`
  - this is committed to version control
  - this DOES NOT store sensitive variables
  - purely to make it simple for developers to see what variables are required

This is the structure I follow. I store all sensitive variables in LastPass and share them to others in my team. Variables can then be copy pasted from LastPass into `terraform.tfvars`.